# Select Count Where Values greater than 0 SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I'm trying to figure out how to return a select query showing a count of all values in a column that are greater than 0. Then in the next column show a count of all values that = 0.

Example:

```
ID  ColumnA
1   1    
2   2
3   1
4   2
5   0
6   0
7   1
```

Would return a result for the select query of:

```
NumberOfGreaterThan0    NumberThatEqual0

5                       2
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregates for this via `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ColumnA > 0 THEN 1 END) AS NumberOfGreaterThan0 
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ColumnA = 0 THEN 1 END) AS NumberThatEqual0
FROM YourTable
```

This works because aggregate functions ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: That's fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a couple of `count` functions over `case` expressions:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN columa > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfGreaterThan0,
       COUNT(CASE columa WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberThatEqual0
FROM   my_table
```